# Object-Detection based API to integrated in Flutter application, connecting with physical device. But there is no responsebody

Tags: flutter, dart, server, android-emulator, fastapi

I want to integrate the object-detection based API into my Flutter application by connecting with my physical device phone. The detected object name will be automatically put into the text Field. First I made it local host but there is connection refuse error. So we change to 10.0.2.2 but then responsebody is still empty. I would appreciate any suggestions I could implement for this.

```
// this is main.py
import io
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from keras.preprocessing import image


app = FastAPI()

vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='max', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

for model_layer in vgg16.layers:
    model_layer.trainable = False

def get_image_embeddings(object_image: image):
    image_array = np.expand_dims(image.img_to_array(object_image), axis=0)
    image_embedding = vgg16.predict(image_array)
    return image_embedding

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World", "var": 1234}


@app.post("/get_similarity_score")
async def get_similarity_score(image1: UploadFile = File(...), image2: UploadFile = File(...)):
    content1 = await image1.read()
    content2 = await image2.read()

    # Create in-memory file-like objects
    f1 = io.BytesIO(content1)
    f2 = io.BytesIO(content2)

    input_im1 = Image.open(f1)
    input_im2 = Image.open(f2)
    input_im1 = input_im1.resize((224, 224))
    input_im2 = input_im2.resize((224, 224))

    input_im1 = get_image_embeddings(input_im1)
    input_im2 = get_image_embeddings(input_im2)

    result = cosine_similarity(input_im1, input_im2).reshape(1, )

    return {float(result[0])}

# Initialize the YOLO model
yolo_model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
custom_model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
custom_model = YOLO('customYolo.pt')

@app.post("/get_detected")
async def get_detected(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # Read the image file
    content = await image.read()
    
    # Create a BytesIO object from the image content
    image_stream = io.BytesIO(content)
    # Open the image using PIL
    input_image = Image.open(image_stream)

    # Perform object detection using YOLO
    result = custom_model(input_image, conf=0.5)
    
    # Extract class names and bounding boxes from the result
    detection_results = []
    for r in result:
        for c in r.boxes.cls:
            detection_results.append(r.names[int(c)])
    
    if detection_results != []:
        return detection_results
    
    result = yolo_model(input_image, conf=0.5 , classes = [24, 25, 26, 27, 32, 36, 38, 39, 41, 45, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 73, 76, 77])
    for r in result:
        for c in r.boxes.cls:
            detection_results.append(r.names[int(c)])
    
    if detection_results == []:
        return ("none")
    
    return detection_results
```

```
this is API.dart 

//api class to connect with detection
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class APIService {
  static Future<String> getSimilarityScore(
      String image1Path, String image2Path) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:8000/get_similarity_score");
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var image1File = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image1', image1Path);
    var image2File = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image2', image2Path);

    request.files.add(image1File);
    request.files.add(image2File);

    var response = await request.send();
    var responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();

    return responseBody;
  }

  static Future<String> getDetected(String image1Path) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:8000/get_detected");
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var image1File = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image1Path);

    request.files.add(image1File);

    var response = await request.send();
    var responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();

    return responseBody;
  }
}
```

```
this is UploadForm.dart

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:lost_and_found/backend/ItemPoster.dart';
import '../backend/User.dart';
import '../backend/API.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import '../backend/Item.dart';
import '../backend/DbHelper.dart';
import '../ui_helper/genDropDown.dart';
import '../ui_helper/genTextFormField.dart';

class UploadForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemPoster itemPoster;
  UploadForm({super.key, required this.itemPoster});
  @override
  _UploadFormState createState() => _UploadFormState();
}

class _UploadFormState extends State<UploadForm> {
  String? selectedColor;
  String? selectedCategory;
  String? selectedLocation;
  String name = '';
  String description = '';

  final _conName = TextEditingController();
  final _conColor = TextEditingController();
  final _conLocation = TextEditingController();
  final _conCategory = TextEditingController();
  final _conDescription = TextEditingController();

  File? _selectedImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Upload Form'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                child: _selectedImage != null
                    ? Image.file(
                        _selectedImage!,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Please select an image",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pickImageFromGallery();
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Pick Image',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _openCamera();
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Open Camera',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              getTextFormField(
                controller: _conName,
                hintName: 'Name',
                icon: Icons.inventory,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              getDropdownFormField(
                hintName: 'Category',
                items: [
                  'IT Gadget',
                  'Stationary',
                  'Personal Belonging',
                  'Bag',
                  'Others'
                ],
                icon: Icons.category,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedCategory = value;
                  });
                },
                value: selectedCategory,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              getDropdownFormField(
                hintName: 'Color',
                items: [
                  'Red',
                  'Green',
                  'Blue',
                  'Yellow',
                  'Orange',
                  'Purple',
                  'Pink',
                  'Brown',
                  'Black',
                  'White',
                  'Gray',
                  'Other'
                ],
                icon: Icons.color_lens,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedColor = value;
                  });
                },
                value: selectedColor,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              getDropdownFormField(
                hintName: 'Location',
                items: [
                  'HM Building',
                  'ECC Building',
                  'Engineering Faculty',
                  'Architect Faculty',
                  'Science Faculty',
                  'Business Faculty',
                  'Art Faculty',
                  'Others'
                ],
                icon: Icons.location_on,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedLocation = value;
                  });
                },
                value: selectedLocation,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              getTextFormField(
                controller: _conDescription,
                hintName: 'Description',
                icon: Icons.description,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _uploadItem();
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Upload',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _uploadItem() async {
    if (_selectedImage == null ||
        selectedCategory == null ||
        selectedColor == null ||
        selectedLocation == null ||
        _conName.text.isEmpty ||
        _conDescription.text.isEmpty) {
      // Display an error message or alert the user about missing information
      return;
    }

    Item item = Item(
      name: _conName.text,
      category: selectedCategory,
      color: selectedColor,
      location: selectedLocation,
      description: _conDescription.text,
      imagePath: _selectedImage!.path,
      itemType: "Lost",
    );

     try {
      await widget.itemPoster.post(item);
      print('Item uploaded successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error uploading item: $e');
    }
  }


  Future<void> _pickImageFromGallery() async {
    try {
      final pickedFile =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
        });

        String detectedObject = await APIService.getDetected(pickedFile.path);
        print('Detected Object: $detectedObject');
        _conName.text = detectedObject;
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error picking image: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _openCamera() async {
    try {
      final pickedFile =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
        });
      } else {
        print('No image selected from camera.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error opening camera: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.